# Term for increasing military presence at sea

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What term expresses an increase of troops or other military units in a standoff between two armies, when no actual fighting has yet occurred?  Specifically, I'm looking for something in the context of a naval battle.

For land-based tactics, I've heard *massing of troops*, but what is a better term for a conflict at sea?

**EDIT:** Ideally, I'm looking for a verb:

> The warships were *VERB*-ing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context of a naval buildup, some phrases that are frequently used:

- "warships *converged* on"
- "warships *deployed* to"
- "The Navy *marshaled* warships in the theater"
- "naval forces were *reinforced* by two additional battleships"

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure, but possibly a military build-up?

Comment: damn, you beat me to it.  It's not specifically naval, though.

Comment: @Rhodri, @Andrew: googling and searching newspapers shows that *naval buildup* is pretty frequently used!

Answer (score 3):

I second the suggestion of "naval buildup", but for the specific example you give "massing" (as you first suggested) or "gathering" is the best fit:

> The warships were massing.

Comment: What about 'amassing'? Would it be a better option for this?

Comment: It's too bad we don't say "The warships were fleeting."

Comment: "naval buildup" sounds like something that can be addressed with a soapy rag.

Comment: @JFW: I don't think so.  Isn't "amass" transitive, as in "amassing a fortune"?

Comment: @Hellion I wouldn't use 'fleeting' as a verb in that context, because [it means 'transient'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fleeting).

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee, that's the source of the humor in my comment.

Comment: @Hellion Seems like I didn't really read your comment properly.

Answer (score 2):

For a naval deployment, "The ships were **gathering**."

Answer (score 1):

A nautical term doesn't come to mind, though I would use "amass" as opposed to "mass" which technically implies a grouping of things or persons, usually unintelligibly.  In other words, sheep mass; armies amass.

Answer (score 1):

Due to an *escalation of force*, the warships were **converging** on the strait of ...